# Transfer function. FACTs method

Tags: transfer-function, schematic

I am trying to use the FACTS method to find the transfer function expression. Could you explain how the resistances Z1, Z2 and Z23 are determined from figure 5.101?
If we consider Figure 5.101b, we can see that both sources are not shorted. Then why does the resistance R3 not participate in the expression for Z2? I have attached a link to this question.

Second question:
Could you answer how to write expressions for Z1, Z2 and Z12 in the attached picture correctly? Thank you.

[Link to the question from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9eRM.jpg)

Explanation for the second question:
[image: Explanation for the second question:]

Source: Linear circuit transfer functions.
Christophe P. Basso

Comment: @VerbalKint - this one's for you.

Comment: The gain of that circuit is easy. This is the \$A\$, \$h\$, or \$k\$ of the transfer function. It's seen easily by first doing Norton-to-Thevenin of \$I_{_\text{IN}}\$ and \$R_1\$ into \$V_{_\text{IN}}=I_{_\text{IN}}\cdot R_1\$. Then, removing the capacitors for a moment, all you have is a simple resistor divider. So \$A=\frac{R_1 \, \cdot \,  R_4}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3 + R_4}\$. That's a given. And its units are \$\Omega\$ as they must be since this is a \$\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{I_{_\text{IN}}}\$ ratio transfer function. The rest of it will be unitless.

Comment: [Though I don't see that schematic (the one you *do* show us) in the section you linked.] Anyway, +1. Hopefully, we'll hook some time from 'VerbalKint'. If not, I may at some point consider applying what little I know of the techniques he writes about in his book. (For my own education more than anything else.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my example, the transfer function is determined using the generalized form which shields you from applying a null-double injection or NDI. The principle is to reuse all the time constants already determined for the denominator and express high-frequency gains in which the energy-storing elements are alternatively set into their high-frequency states: a short circuit for a capacitor and an open circuit for an inductor. Then, combining these terms all together leads you to the numerator expression.

Now, to determine a resistance (or an impedance), the theoretical approach is to excite the port with a current source \$I_T\$ and express the voltage \$V_T\$ collected across its terminals:

[image]

This method always work and can lead to complicated results, especially with controlled sources but, sometimes, you don't have choice. One alternative, is to consider *inspecting* the circuit: rather than applying a test generator, you "look" through the connecting terminals and infer, in your mind, the equivalent resistance you "see" or would measure with an ohm-meter. You can also do this inspection exercise by breaking down the circuit into a succession of simplified sketches of course.

The exercise is similar to find the high-frequency gains and the example you gave in the page you pasted is that of a transimpedance circuit shown below:

[image]

Here, you have to find the high-frequency transfer function linking the output voltage to the output current when the caps are alternatively shorted or open circuited. You immediately can see that if \$C_1\$ or \$C_3\$ are shorted, there is no response implying that the transfer function in these modes is zero. The only mode in which a response exists is when \$C_2\$ is shorted. In that case, the output voltage is simply \$V_{out}=I_{in}(R_1||R_2)\$ and thus \$\frac{V_{out}}{I_{in}}=Z^2=R_1||R_2\$. In this notation, the 2 in the exponent-like notation indicates that element 2 (\$C_2\$) is set in high frequency while the other are in dc state. In this configuration, \$R_3\$ does not participate because there is no current flowing into it. Should a resistance load \$V_{out}\$ in a different circuit, then, yes, \$R_3\$ would enter the picture but not here.

Now, if I look your sketch which is not the one I used in my example, this is a second-order circuit with \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ alternatively set in their high-frequency state or open circuited. When calculating the high-frequency gains, you forgot to short some of the caps. and there is no zero at all in this new circuit:

[image]

Now some comments triggered by your questions:

1. to determine the time constants of the denominator \$D(s)\$, the original stimulus is not used in the exercise. For instance, if you want to determine \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\$, \$V_{in}\$ which is the stimulus applied to the input of your network is turned off and replaced by a 0-V source or a short circuit. Then, you apply the test generator method \$V_T\$ and \$I_T\$ (or inspection) to each of the energy-storing elements alternatively set in their dc or high-frequency state.
2. for the numerator \$N(s)\$, you can either apply a NDI but it can be intimidating to new comers or use the generalized form. This form builds on the already-determined time constants in \$D(s)\$ and you have to bring the stimulus back. Then, you determine the gains of your circuit - \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\$ for instance - when the energy-storing elements are alternatively set in dc or high-frequency state. It is usually simple as any cap. shorting the path to the output immediately brings 0 in the transfer function. If not, like with \$R_1\$ in my figure, then it indicates that there is a zero in the transfer function.

Based on the suggested responses you gave in your drawing, it looks like you were calculating impedances while \$I_{in}\$ was brought back. If \$I_{in}\$ is there, then you have to consider the high-frequency gains only. Let me know if it makes better sense now and congrats for learning the FACTs, this is one the best tools to acquire!

Comment: thanks for the detailed description. Special thanks for introducing me to the FACT's method.

Comment: With pleasure of course : ) and a happy holiday season to you!