# Finding the transfer function and damping coefficient an LCR circuit

Tags: passive-networks, circuits

I am trying to determine the general transfer function of the following circuit. [image]

Shouldn’t the transfer function just be \$R + \frac{Z_CZ_L}{(Z_C+Z_L)}\$? I am trying to then use the transfer function to solve for the damping coefficient by plugging in values for R and C, but I can’t seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

> *Shouldnt the transfer function just be R + (ZcZl/(Zc+Zl))*

No, that's the input impedance. A transfer function relates Vout to Vin using the Laplace operator, \$s\$. Drilling down through your circuit starting from here: -

$$\dfrac{V_O}{V_I}\hspace{0.5cm}=\dfrac{Z_P}{R+Z_P}$$

Where \$Z_P\$ is the impedance of the inductor and capacitor in parallel. This becomes....

$$\dfrac{V_O}{V_I}\hspace{0.5cm}=\hspace{0.5cm}\dfrac{sL}{s^2 LCR + sL +R}\hspace{0.5cm}=\hspace{0.5cm}\dfrac{s\frac{1}{CR}}{s^2 + s\frac{1}{CR} +\frac{1}{LC}}$$

```
$$\dfrac{V_O}{V_I}\hspace{0.5cm}=\hspace{0.5cm}\dfrac{sL}{s^2 LCR + sL +R}\hspace{0.5cm}=\hspace{0.5cm}\dfrac{s\frac{1}{CR}}{s^2 + s\frac{1}{CR} +\frac{1}{LC}}$$
```

Directly above is the latex formula (in case you are interested in prettying your algebra).

> *I am trying to then use the transfer function to solve for the damping
> coefficient by plugging in values for R and C, but I cant seem to
> figure this out.*

The denominator above is of the form where: \$\hspace{0.5cm}2\zeta\omega_N = \frac{1}{CR}\hspace{0.5cm}\$ and \$\hspace{0.5cm}\omega_N^2 = \frac{1}{LC}\$

- Zeta (\$\zeta\$) is the damping ratio.
- \$\omega_N\$ is the natural (undamped) resonant frequency (sometimes called \$\omega_0\$)

Hence, \$\hspace{0.5cm}\zeta\hspace{0.5cm} =\hspace{0.5cm} \frac{1}{2R}\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\hspace{0.5cm}\leftarrow \hspace{0.2cm}\$ (corrected as per comments)

Or just use the calculator [from my basic website](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20BPF/RCL%20BPF.html): -

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for your response! I think I am still a bit confused as to where the components of the transfer function are coming from. I understand that Vout=VL since we are measuring the voltage across the inductor. Do you mind going into a bit more detail as to where the denominator of your transfer function is derived from the circuit? Thanks!

Comment: @BiggestGrits I've added a line to help

Comment: @Andyaka I think your fraction within the sqrt for zeta is upside down. Could you check that and see if I'm right?

Comment: @periblepsis oops you are quite correct. Fixing....

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks. I'll +1 now. I added something I was writing when I noticed your error. Decided to finish it off, anyway.

Comment: Hi, sorry to keep asking, but Im confused where the RCL(s^2) term in the denominator is coming from. Simplifying the transfer function would yield Zl/(ZlZcR+R+Zl)- correct? so in this case wouldn't substituting in values for L and C cancel out the s term in the denominator? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the input supply and don't bus wires:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFphnq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Without over-thinking things too much yet, the above may be a little easier to notice as a simple voltage divider: \$V_{_\text{OUT}}\$ is just a divided-down part of \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$. So \$V_{_\text{OUT}}=V_{_\text{IN}}\cdot\frac{Z_{_\text{C}}\mid\mid Z_{_\text{L}}}{R+\left(Z_{_\text{C}}\mid\mid Z_{_\text{L}}\right)}\$.

Or put another way, \$\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{V_{_\text{IN}}}=\frac{Z_{_\text{C}}\mid\mid Z_{_\text{L}}}{R+\left(Z_{_\text{C}}\mid\mid Z_{_\text{L}}\right)}\$. That right side is the so-called transfer function.

Plugging in \$Z_{_\text{C}}=\frac1{s\,C}\$ and \$Z_{_\text{L}}=s\cdot L\$ you might get this: \$\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{V_{_\text{IN}}}=\frac{L\,s}{R\,C\,L\,s^2+L\,s+R}\$. You don't need the numerator to work out the damping factor. All you need are the coefficients in the denominator, \$a_2\,s^2+a_1\,s+a_0\$, as \$\zeta=\frac12\frac{a_1}{\sqrt{a_2\cdot a_0}}=\frac12\frac{L}{\sqrt{\left(L\,C\,R\right)\cdot R}}=\frac1{2\,R}\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$.

(If you need or want an explanation about how to derive \$\zeta\$, ask.)

### Some help

It appears you may want some help about arriving at a transfer function (not in any of the 3 standardized forms I usually consider, but still algebraically correct):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{V_{_\text{IN}}}&=\frac{Z_{_\text{C}}\mid\mid Z_{_\text{L}}}{R+\left(Z_{_\text{C}}\mid\mid Z_{_\text{L}}\right)}=
\frac{\frac1{s\,C}\mid\mid s\,L}{R+\left(\frac1{s\,C}\mid\mid s\,L\right)}=
\frac{\frac{\frac1{s\,C}\,\cdot \,s\,L}{\frac1{s\,C}+ s\,L}}{R+\frac{\frac1{s\,C}\,\cdot \,s\,L}{\frac1{s\,C}+ s\,L}}
\\\\
&\cdot\frac{\frac{s\,C}{s\,C}}{\frac{s\,C}{s\,C}}=\frac{\frac{L\,s}{L\,C\,s^2+1}}{R+\frac{s\,L}{L\,C\,s^2+1}}
\\\\
&\cdot \frac{L\,C\,s^2+1}{L\,C\,s^2+1}=\frac{L\,s}{R\,C\,L\,s^2+L\,s+R}
\end{align*}$$

The above is still considered to be kind of ugly. It doesn't isolate the things people want to know: \$\omega_{_0}\$ and \$\zeta\$ or \$Q\$, for example. Nor the gain, \$K\$ (or \$A\$ or a lot of other letters as there is less of a standard here.)

### For Later

Not for now, but some later time when you can consider these things more deeply, it may be helpful if you learn to abstract away from the details and just stand back to see a larger picture. Another way of writing a transfer function is: \$\left[\text{output operator}\right]V_{_\text{OUT}}=\left[\text{input operator}\right]V_{_\text{IN}}\$. Read this as, *"Some output operator acting on Vout must always equal some input operator acting on Vin."* The transfer function is then just the ratio of these two operators.

For voltage dividers like the above, the *operators* are just conductance operators and the equation is just a matter of basic KCL:

$$\left[\text{operator for conductance out of Vout}\right]V_{_\text{OUT}}=\left[\text{operator for conductance in from Vin}\right]V_{_\text{IN}}$$

If you replace impedance, \$Z_i\$, with admittance \$Y_i\$, then in your schematic case:

$$\left[Y_{_\text{R}}+Y_{_\text{C}}+Y_{_\text{L}}\right]V_{_\text{OUT}}=\left[Y_{_\text{R}}\right]V_{_\text{IN}}$$

Which here just says that current in equals current out. Basic KCL.

Later, this larger view will come in handy. For now, don't worry about it. Operators are for later on. Just get ready for the idea.

Comment: Hi, after finding the transfer function, wouldnt the s^2 term in the denominator actually cancel since you would be multiplying 1/sC by sL?

Comment: @BiggestGrits I don't understand what you are seeing. But clearly there are two answers here which arrive at the same result for zeta. Perhaps consider editing your question and inserting more details? Or write a longer comment so I can follow your logic? I generally get the idea that you think multiplying 1/sC by sL should cause the two 's's to cancel. But I don't understand any of why you are doing that. Do you need to be step-wise walked through the algebra?

Comment: No problem! I think I'm really just confused about simplifying the transfer function. I understand now that the transfer function is just Vo/Vi = Zp/(R+Zp), where Zp is the total impedance of the two components in parallel. Maybe I am not calculating Zp correctly, I have Zp = Zl/(ZcZl+1). So substitution for Zp gives me Vo/Vin = Zl/(ZlZcR+R+L). Substituting for Zl = sL and Zc = 1/sC in this case does not give me the same transfer function as everyone else. hopefully this is enough detail!

Comment: @BiggestGrits I added something I hope helps out.

Comment: @BiggestGrits And while I do show how to perform some algebra to get an s^2 in the denominator, I still didn't show any development of how zeta is extracted from that particular resulting transfer function. That's even more mathematics I'd need to add. Some of it seems to be already on EESE, though. See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/622340/330261) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/632840/330261), for example. Still looking to see if any others exist here...